# Infinite Gamma Derivative Identity

Tags: gamma-function, polygamma

We have 
$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\;dx \tag{1}
$$
We also have
$$
\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\, x^{z-1}e^{-x}=\log(x)^n e^{-x}x^{z-1}, \;\; z>1 \tag{2}
$$
If we create an operator
$$
\hat{O}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n} = e^{\frac{d}{dz}}
$$
and apply it to both sides of $(1)$, we get
$$
\hat{O}\Gamma(z)=\hat{O}\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\;dx 
$$
if we allow this under the integral sign, then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}x^{z-1}e^{-x}\right)\;dx
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\log(x)^n}{n!}\right)x^{z-1}e^{-x}\;dx 
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z}e^{-x}\;dx
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)
$$
this seems to hold numerically for $z>1$, for $z=1$, the value jumps between $1/2$ and $3/2$, which is curious as the average is right, but then $(2)$ doesn't hold anymore. The $n^{th}$ derivative of $\Gamma(z)$ seems to get increasingly complicated with large $n$.There is always a factor of $\Gamma(z)$ as well so it seems more to be a statement that 
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\Gamma(z)=z \tag{3}
$$

Can this be proven in another way?

Is there any information about the derivative of $\Gamma(z)$ that makes this identity more obvious?

I notice that if we replace $\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\Gamma(z)$ with $\Gamma(z) \log(z)^n$, then the equation would still hold. Is that related at all?

---

I've noticed that if we replace $\psi^{(t)}(z)$ as $z^t$ then
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\frac{d^n}{dz^n} \Gamma(z) \big|_{\psi^{(t)}(z) \to z^t} = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right\}z^{n-k}
$$
with $\left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right\}$ as Stirling numbers of the second kind.

We end up with a kind of ladder operator
$$
e^{\frac{d}{dz}}\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)
$$
$$
e^{-\frac{d}{dz}}\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z-1)
$$

Comment: Is it not simply the Taylor expansion for $\Gamma(x+1)$?

Comment: @PaulEnta It does look similar but I thought it was missing the $(x-a)^n$ looking term. What point $a$ should the series be taken about?

Comment: @PaulEnta I guess if we set $a=z$ for the expansion of $\Gamma(z+1)$ then all the powers go to $1$ and the identity is reclaimed. Good spot if that's what you meant. However I've never set the expansion point to a function of the main variable before. Is that legal?

Comment: Yes, it is valid to choose arbitrarily the values of $a$ and $b$ in the Taylor expansion of $f(a+b)$ near $a$ or near $b$, provided that the series converges...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you have discovered the [shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20and%20in%20particular,is%20called%20the%20lag%20operator.). Note that
$$
e^{\partial_x}x^a=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\partial_x x^a=x^a\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-a)_k}{k!}(-x)^{-k}=x^a{_1F}_0(-a;-;-x^{-1})=(x+1)^a,
$$
where $(s)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol and ${_pF}_q(\mathbf a;\mathbf b;z)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function. Given this identity we can write $t^x$ as a power series to find
$$
e^{\partial_x}t^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\log^kt}{k!}e^{\partial_x}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\log^kt}{k!}(x+1)^k=t^{x+1}
$$
and so,
$$
e^{\partial_x}\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{\partial_x}t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty t^xe^{-t}\,\mathrm dt=\Gamma(x+1).
$$
With a little work you can easily extend this result to the more general operator shift operator $e^{t\partial_x}$.